# Newbie Trying to Build a Javascript Age Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a new self-learner and have recently taken on javascript. I have an assignment (from an online code camp) that I just cant seem to make pass. I feel like I understand the basics of it, but I can't write it in a functional way. Can anyone help me here?

[image: Age Calculator]

The question is in the attached image.

My code looks a little something like:

```
function ageCalculator(name, yearOfBirth, currentYear) {
  var age = currentYear - yearOfBirth;
  return (name + "is" + age + "years old.");
  console.log(ageCalculator("Miranda", 1983, 2015));
}
```

I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: From the [`java` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java): "*Java (**not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript or JS**) ...*"  - And from the [`javascript` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript): "*JavaScript (**not to be confused with Java**)*"

Comment: **Unrelated:** Miranda, Venezuela? `(:`

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text. The question should be in your question post.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling the function `ageCalculator` just after the return statement.  Anything just after the return statement won't be called.

Just pull that call outside.

```js
function ageCalculator(name, yearOfBirth, currentYear) {
  var age = currentYear - yearOfBirth;
  return (name + " is " + age + " years old.");  
}

console.log(ageCalculator("Miranda", 1983, 2015));
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the function outside the function declaration.

```js
function ageCalculator(name, yearOfBirth, currentYear) {
    var age = currentYear - yearOfBirth;
    return (name + " is " + age + " years old.");
}
    
console.log(ageCalculator("Miranda", 1983, 2015));
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you `return`, the function stops immediately: it'll never get to your `console.log` the way it is now. Call `console.log` and the function itself *outside* your function, you don't want an infinite recursive loop.

Also make sure to add proper spacing:

```js
function ageCalculator(name, yearOfBirth, currentYear) {
  var age = currentYear - yearOfBirth;
  return (name + " is " + age + " years old.");
}
console.log(ageCalculator("Miranda", 1983, 2015));
```